# Can't connect to mobile hotspot

Tags: internet

I am a new ubuntu user. Using 16.04 version. Without internet connection making my life standstill. 
I shortened my mobile hotspot name to a single character, I made my hotspot open. Nothing seems to works. Some solution in the net seems too complex. 
Can any one help me?

Comment: How do you know it does not work? What have you tried and what error messages do you get?

Comment: You are trying to connect to the Internet from your computer by using your cell phone?

Comment: First it tries to connects. Then after couple of seconds a message comes up,  " Disconnected - you are now offline".